# Kotlin] I want to send some data from One class to Other class by using Intent

Tags: android, firebase, object, kotlin, dbcontext

I just want to say sorry to my English skill

I've studied the Android Studio and Kotlin these days.

but I'd got a problem on RecyclerViewer and Adapter, for Intent method

[work flow chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apA6F.png)

this image, this is what i want to do

so i coded the three classes

ShoppingAppActivity.kt, MyAdapter.kt, CartActivity.kt

At ShoppingAppActivity, If I click the itemId ( in the Red box texts)

I make it move to other context(CartActivity)

[ShoppingAppActivity working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfkLS.png)

if i clicked the red box then

[cartStatus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfXdC.png)

go to cart Activity

it worked but already I said, I just want to send only send itemID
covert to String (i will use toString())

SO i tried to use Intent method in ShoppingAppActivity.kt

```
///PROBLEM PART
        adapter?.setOnItemClickListener{
            val nextIntent = Intent(this, CartActivity::class.java)
            //nextIntent.putExtra("itemID", )
            startActivity(nextIntent)
        }
        ///PROBLEM PART
```

like this but the problem is I don't know what am i have to put the parameter in

nextIntent.putExtra("itemID", )

what should i do?

I think, I should fix MyAdaptor.kt or ShopingAppActivity.kt for this problem.

But in my knowledge, this is my limit. :-(

below

Full Codes of ShoppingAppActivity.kt, MyAdapter.kt, CartActivity.kt

ShoppingAppActivity.kt

```
class ShoppingAppActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityShoppingAppBinding
    private var adapter: MyAdapter? = null
    private val db : FirebaseFirestore = Firebase.firestore
    private val itemsCollectionRef = db.collection("items")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityShoppingAppBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        updateList()

        binding.recyclerViewItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        adapter = MyAdapter(this, emptyList())
        binding.recyclerViewItems.adapter = adapter


        ///PROBLEM PART
        adapter?.setOnItemClickListener{
            val nextIntent = Intent(this, CartActivity::class.java)
            //nextIntent.putExtra("itemID", )
            startActivity(nextIntent)
        }
        ///PROBLEM PART
    }

    private fun updateList() {
        itemsCollectionRef.get().addOnSuccessListener {
            val items = mutableListOf<Item>()
            for (doc in it) {
                items.add(Item(doc))
            }
            adapter?.updateList(items)
        }
    }
}
```

MyAdapter.kt

```
data class Item(val id: String, val name: String, val price: Int, val cart: Boolean) {
    constructor(doc: QueryDocumentSnapshot) :
        this(doc.id, doc["name"].toString(), doc["price"].toString().toIntOrNull() ?: 0, doc["cart"].toString().toBoolean() ?: false)
constructor(key: String, map: Map<*, *>) :
        this(key, map["name"].toString(), map["price"].toString().toIntOrNull() ?: 0, map["cart"].toString().toBoolean() ?: false)
}

class MyViewHolder(val binding: ItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

class MyAdapter(private val context: Context, private var items: List<Item>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {

fun interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(student_id: String)
}

private var itemClickListener: OnItemClickListener? = null

fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener) {
    itemClickListener = listener
}

fun updateList(newList: List<Item>) {
    items = newList
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val binding: ItemBinding = ItemBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = items[position]
    val itemID : String
    holder.binding.textID.text = item.id
    holder.binding.textName.text = item.name
    if(item.cart)
    {
        holder.binding.textCart.text = "in Cart"
    }
    else
    {
        holder.binding.textCart.text = ""
    }

    holder.binding.textID.setOnClickListener {
        AlertDialog.Builder(context).setMessage("You clicked ${item.id}.").show()
        itemClickListener?.onItemClick(item.id)
    }
    holder.binding.textName.setOnClickListener {
        //AlertDialog.Builder(context).setMessage("You clicked ${student.name}.").show()
        itemClickListener?.onItemClick(item.id)
    }
    //return item.id.toString()
}

override fun getItemCount() = items.size
```

}

CartActivity.kt

```
class CartActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityCartBinding
    private val db: FirebaseFirestore = Firebase.firestore
    private val itemsCollectionRef = db.collection("items")
    private var adapter: MyAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityCartBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        updateList()

        //binding.recyclerViewItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        //adapter = MyAdapter(this, emptyList())
        //binding.recyclerViewItems.adapter = adapter


        binding.changeCartStatus.setOnClickListener{
            //change the button's text if the itemID is corrected
            //if(){
               // binding.changeCartStatus.text = ""
            //}
        }
    }

    private fun updateList() {
        itemsCollectionRef.get().addOnSuccessListener {
            val items = mutableListOf<Item>()
            for (doc in it) {
                items.add(Item(doc))
            }
            adapter?.updateList(items)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement listener to your activity

```
 class ShoppingAppActivity : AppCompatActivity() ,MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
```

In oncreate add below line after adapter

```
 adapter?.setOnItemClickListener(this)
```

Then override its method

```
  override fun onItemClick(id: String){
      val nextIntent = Intent(this, CartActivity::class.java)
      nextIntent.putExtra("itemID",id )
      startActivity(nextIntent)
  }
```